# OS X Mavericks Guest Mode with Filevault → Safari flickers + crashes

Tags: macos, safari, filevault, guest-account

Did anyone tried out the Guest Account feature in Mac OS X Mavericks with Filevault2 = on?

I did and
- Safari flickers (like with wrong graphic driver) → https://discussions.apple.com/message/23784151#23784151
- Safari / the complete system crashs and freezes on several websites.
Summary it's not usable! :(

Does anyone have similar issues?
Who does know a solution or has an idea to get the bug?
Thank you!

Comment: What sort of Mac are you on?  I've played with it a little on a 2013 MacBook Air 13-inch and it seems ok...the graphics do seem just a little "off" (not sure how to describe it) but otherwise appears stable

Comment: i have the same system

Comment: Same issue under 10.9.1? Does Safari report anything in log files?

Comment: yep same issue + unfortunately you have no access to any logfiles in guestmode

Answer (score -1):

The Guest account only appears on the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen if iCloud's Find My Mac is enabled. It's essentially a way to encourage someone to get online from that laptop without having to unlock the encryption. Once online, the laptop phones home to the Find My Mac service immediately with its current IP and location information.

Long story short, the Safari-Only Mode is not really meant for everyday use. It's meant to be a trap for thieves.

Comment: wrong, it appears without iclouds find my mac as well! + what other possiblities do have to leave you mac open for guests?